# What is meant by "continuously ordered according to the increasing value of $t$"

Tags: complex-analysis

**Please Help Me:**

> Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous map. Then the image points $f(t);t\in[a,b]$ are continuously ordered according to the increasing value of $t.$

I don't understand what is meant by "**continuously ordered according to the increasing value of $t$**" and how can it be shown?

Of course it doesn't mean $\forall ~x,y,z\in[a,b]$ with $x< y< z,$ $|f(x)-f(y)|$$\leq |f(x)-f(z)|...(1)$ for if we consider $f:[0,2\pi]:t\mapsto \cos 2t+i\sin 2t$ then $|f(0)-f(2\pi)|<|f(0)-f(\pi)|.$ Then does it suggest $\exists$ an interval in which $1$ holds?

> **Ref: [Churchill, Brown, Verhey [3rd Ed]](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007EQOC66)** 
>   [image]

Also how can it be guranteed that $Im~f$ always looks like a line (not necessarily straight)?

Comment: What are you quoting from?

Comment: @AdamSaltz: See edit

Comment: It means $(x(t_0), y(t_0)) \lt (x(t_1), y(t_1))$ if $t_0\lt t_1$.

Comment: @user69810: How do your define order in $\mathbb C?$

Comment: The ordering is only on the image-it's induced by the ordering on $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @KevinCarlson: you mean $(x(t_0),y(t_0))<(x(t_1),y(t_1))\iff x(t_0)<x(t_1),y(t_0)<y(t_1)?$

Comment: @SugataAdhya I am not saying this is a linear order. I am interpreting the text. I don't have this book so I don't know what is written next. Perhaps the author is restricting his paths to be injective?